# Django OAuth Toolkit protected_resource for class-based views

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-class-based-views, oauth2-toolkit

I want to use `@protected_resource()` decorator with class-based views.

But I get error: `'update_card' object has no attribute 'get_full_path'`

In documentation Class-based views page is empty https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views/class_based.html

How I can protect my class-based view with decorator?

Answer (score 1):

I've found solution myself:

Instead of `django.views.generic.View` I used `oauth2_provider.views.generic.ProtectedResourceView`.